# os.fork problem

Tags: python, linux

I am working on a mission-critical program and my boss asked me to write a program that would protect this mission-critical program from being terminated for a long time. This mission-critical program is written with python. And I wrote a protector program  in C. But I encounter a problem when dealing with os.fork. Please see the following codes for reference

```
pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    execlp(myprotector, myprotector, ......)
elif pid > 0:
    return_pid = pid
```

I used `ps aux | grep myprotector` in my terminal to list my programs. but the pid listed by `ps aux` is different from the pid generated in the above codes. I don't know why. There do exist a pid that corresponds the pid generated from codes above, but it is a  process. Could you guys please help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `protector`? Do you want to keep the program running? If yes, then there are many other solutions for it (supervisord, daemontools, monit, ...)

Comment: "...but it is a process".  _What_ process?  Is this "mission-critical program" launched by a shell script?

Comment: Perhaps this is unrelated to your goal, but if you want to ensure your mission-critical program is restarted if ever terminated, check out Monit http://mmonit.com/monit.

Answer (score 1):

Options:

http://supervisord.org/

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zdaemon/2.0.4